# Refrescar URL y recuperar los datos ingresados en el formulario

Tags: php

Qué tal, estoy haciendo un sitio web y estoy teniendo un problema al refrescar la página ya que ingreso datos a los inputs del formulario y refresco la URL y se eliminan los datos automáticamente, cómo le podría hacer para que no pase eso de antemano les agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: En estricto rigor el navegador debería pedir un reenvio del formulario cuando este es enviado y se actualiza. Es probable que la solicitud ya se haya consumado y estés redirigiendo, por eso pierdes el "formulario" de todas formas son especulaciones, pon tu codigo para poder ayudarte. Recuerda leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para crear preguntas de calidad.

Answer (score -1):

Podrías deshabilitar la actualización (F5) de la página, y al mismo tiempo, advertir que se abandonará la url y se perderán los datos:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if (tecla = 116) return false
}

function no_atras(){
  history.go(1)
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  if (confirm('¿Desea salir?')) {
    // Cancelar el evento unload
    event.preventDefault();
    // Chrome requiere devolver returnValue.
    event.returnValue = '';
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body onload="no_atras()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta, "deshabilitar" la opción de actualizar quizá corrompe sus reglas de negocio. Además si se utilizan los botones de actualizar del propio navegador, parte de tu código pasa a ser inútil. Recuerda utilizar la opción de comentarios antes de crear una respuesta. puedes leer [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)